# How do we find the mean and variance of a single random variable given two other variables?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

> Let $Y_1 =\frac{1}{2}X^2 − 1$ and $Y_2 =\frac{1}{2}X − 1$, where $X$ is a random variable whose mean is positive.
>   Moreover, we know that the mean of $Y_1$ is $2$, and the variance of $Y_2$ is $0.5$. Find the mean and variance of $X$.

This seems simple, but I am stumped. Any ideas?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

Apply the properties you know of [expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Properties) and [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties) to
$$2 =E[Y_1]  = E\left[\frac{1}{2}X^2-1\right]=\frac{1}{2}E[X^2]-1$$

and hence $E[X^2]=6$. Next
$$\frac{1}{2} = \text{Var}(Y_2) = \text{Var}\left(\frac{1}{2}X-1\right) = \frac{1}{4}\text{Var}(X)$$
and hence $\text{Var}(X) = 2$.
Finally use 
$$\text{Var}(X) = E(X^2)-\{E(X)\}^2$$
to solve for the positive expectation  $E[X] = 2$.

Comment: Awesome, that helps, with E(x), but with variance? Do you subtract the mean squared?

Comment: @MPinker That doesn't sound right. If you found $E[X]$, then were able to find $\text{Var}(X)$. The answers are $\sqrt 2$ and $2$ respectively. Do you get that?

Comment: Where do you get that? The answers should be 2 and 2.

Comment: @MPinker Ok, I copied the problem wrong. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @MPinker If you found this answer helpful, consider giving a [check mark](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). You will be able to up vote when you have 15 rep. Good luck.